# NestJS - Communication between 2 microservice

Tags: nestjs

I built a Http app and 2 microservices using TCP protocol.

This is my application diagram.

[image]

```
// Http App/app.service.ts
constructor() {
    this.accountService = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8877,
      },
    });

    this.friendService = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080,
      },
    });
  }
```

I tried to send message from Account Service to Friend Service by `@Messagepattern()`.

ClientProxy is set up each service. But it doesn't work.

I read offical documentaion `@nestjs/microservices`, But i don't know which one is appropriate.

Is there right way to send message from one microservice to another microservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a message broker, something like RabbitMQ or Kafka, ie for RabbitMQ enter the command below and create a RabbitMQ container.

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 0.0.0.0:5672:5672 -p 0.0.0.0:15672:15672 -d rabbitmq:3-management
```

Then pass RabbitMQ options to your `main.ts` bootstrap function:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const rabbitmqPort = 5672
  const rabbitmqHost = 127.0.0.1
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [
        `amqp://${rabbitmqHost}:${rabbitmqPort}`,
      ],
      queue: 'myqueue',
      queueOptions: {
        durable: false,
      },
    },
  });


  app
    .startAllMicroservices(() => {
      logger.log('Microservice is listening!');
    })
    .listen(3000, () => {
      logger.log('Api Server is listening on 3000');
    });
}

bootstrap();
```

For receiving messages:

```
  @MessagePattern('my_pattern')
  async myController(
    @Payload() data: MYDTO,
  ): Promise<MY TYPE> {
    return await this.accountService.myFunction(data);
  }
```

Now when a client sends a message on `myqueue` with `my_pattern` pattern, the data that client sends will be `data` which comes from `@playload()` annotation.

For sending messages on any queue you need to add RabbitMQ configurations to your  application module, ie `account.module.ts`, by the assumption that you want to send a message on FriendService

```
const rabbitmqPort = 5672
const rabbitmqHost = 127.0.0.1

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: 'Friend',
        useFactory: {
          transport: Transport.RMQ,
          options: {
            urls: [
             `amqp://${rabbitmqHost}:${rabbitmqPort}`,
            ],
            queue: 'friend_queue',
            queueOptions: {
              durable: false,
            },
          },
        }
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AccountController],
  providers: [AccountService],
})
export class AccountModule {}
```

And then inject `Friend` client to your service constructor like this:

```
    @Inject('Friend')
    private friendClient: ClientProxy,
```

Send messages like this:

```
      const myVar = await this.friendClient.send('Some_pattern', {SOME DATA}).toPromise();
```

Set up all the above configurations for your both microservices and it shall work.